# Android application failed during start, fatal exception

Tags: android

Fatal exception. I am kind a new in android programming so hopefully you can get it. For more info or more code just write a comment I can add.

here is the error:

```
03-17 17:38:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 17:38:42.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  
activity     
ComponentInfo{com.example.mandatoryassigment/com.example.mandatoryassigment.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is  
'android.R.id.list'
```

You have any idea? The application is trying to show the list (ListActivity).

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Its already solved, guys below were right I had to create list in xml file but I dont understand it because it was working 1 hour before then something happened and it was showing this error. Dont you know why it happened like this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you change the code in the last one hour? It has to have been changed - one possibility is that this list was being dynamically created in the java class and then that section was deleted or the xml file was changed or something like that

Comment: maybe you changed from Activity to ListActivity?

Comment: Yes I did change the code and yes it might be possible i deleted anything in class but i did not change anything in xml file, anyway thank you at least now I know also this is possible ;D.

Comment: Nope, all the time it was ListActivity ;) and list was nicely working etc. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a ListView in your xml layout that you set to the ListActivity with id  `android.R.id.list`

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently referring to a ListView object which is supposed to have an id R.id.list - which is missing in the xml file. You need to create that.

Comment: Thanks, its working can you check my comment above please?